# How to create multiple node characters in sprite kit /SKphysics joint?

Tags: sprite-kit, nodes, game-physics, skphysicsbody

I am creating a game and for my character his legs and torso have separate animations so they are separate nodes with separate physics bodies. I am having a lot of trouble linking the torso and the legs together however, linking them is not the problem, keeping them linked is. While moving around sometimes the hero's torso slides off of the legs. Kind of funny but not practical lol. Here is my physics coding

```
enum BodyType:UInt32 {

case bullet1 = 2

case enemy1 =  4
case enemy2 =  16
case enemy3 =  32

case desertForegroundCase = 64

case tank11 =  128
case tank12 =  256
case tank13 =  512

case tank21 =  1024
case tank22 =  2048
case tank23 =  4056

case tank31 =  8112
case tank32 =  16224
case tank33 =  32448

case cliff1 =  64856
case cliff2 =  129212

case soldierT = 258424
case soldierL = 516848

static let ground: UInt32 = 1
}
     func CreateScene (){

    desertBackground.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width / 2, y: 
    frame.size.height / 2)
    desertBackground.size = CGSize (width: 1136, height: 640)
    desertBackground.zPosition = -5
    desertForegroundImage.position = CGPointMake(568, 100)
    desertForegroundImage.zPosition = -1
    let desertForeground = SKSpriteNode(texture: 
    desertForegroundTexture, size:CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))
        desertForeground.position = CGPointMake(568, 100)
    let desertForegroundBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: 
    desertForegroundTexture, size: CGSize(width: 1136, height: 200))
    desertForegroundBody.dynamic = false
    desertForegroundBody.affectedByGravity = false
    desertForegroundBody.allowsRotation = false
    desertForegroundBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.ground
    desertForegroundBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue 
    | BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
    BodyType.soldierL.rawValue | BodyType.soldierT.rawValue
    desertForeground.physicsBody = desertForegroundBody
    desertForeground.zPosition = -1

    self.addChild(desertForegroundImage)
    self.addChild(desertForeground)
    self.addChild(desert gully)

    }
   func CreateHero (){

    soldierLegs.position = CGPoint(x: 405 , y: 139)
    soldierLegs.zPosition = 1
    soldierLegs.anchorPoint.x = 0.6
    soldierLegs.anchorPoint.y = 0.7

    let soldierLegsBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
    soldierLegs.size)
    soldierLegsBody.dynamic = true
    soldierLegsBody.affectedByGravity = true
    soldierLegsBody.allowsRotation = false
    //body.restitution = 0.4
    soldierLegsBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierL.rawValue
    soldierLegsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
    BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
    BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
    soldierLegs.physicsBody = soldierLegsBody

    soldierTorso.position = soldierLegs.position
    soldierTorso.zPosition = 2
    soldierTorso.anchorPoint.x = 0.25
    soldierTorso.anchorPoint.y = 0.1

    let soldierTorsoBody:SKPhysicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: 
    soldierTorso.size)
    soldierTorsoBody.dynamic = true
    soldierTorsoBody.affectedByGravity = true
    soldierTorsoBody.allowsRotation = false
    soldierTorsoBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.soldierT.rawValue
    soldierTorsoBody.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.enemy1.rawValue | 
    BodyType.enemy2.rawValue | BodyType.enemy3.rawValue  | 
    BodyType.desertForegroundCase.rawValue
    soldierTorso.physicsBody = soldierTorsoBody
    let joint  = 
    SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(soldierLegs.physicsBody!, bodyB: 
    soldierTorso.physicsBody!, anchor: soldierLegs.position)

    soldierLegsBody.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ground
    soldierTorsoBody.collisionBitMask = BodyType.ground

    self.addChild(soldierTorso)
    self.addChild(soldierLegs)
    self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

[image]
    }

That's about how far he will slide off. Is there a way to just code one physics body with 2 separate nodes? or am i just missing a little code? Any help is help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, after declaring the physics joint

```
let joint = 
SKPhysicsJointFixed.jointWithBodyA(soldierLegs.physicsBody!, 
bodyB:soldierTorso.physicsBody!, anchor: soldierLegs.position)
```

declare the second node of the joint's dynamic value as false by

```
    joint.bodyB.dynamic = false
```

then reposition the node using the update function

```
 override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

   soldierTorso.position = soldierLegs.position

}
```

Positioning the extra node 60 times per second should make sure the node does not move, or for a higher frame rate or a smoother run im sure positioning it 5 - 20 times per second would do fine however positioning the torso 60 times per second did not reduce any frame rate speed for me

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the two physics bodies will be colliding with each other then since you have the dynamic set to true they will move you can set the dynamic to false or

In the BodyType Struct add a new constant like this:

```
static let none: UInt32 = 0
```

Then you can add this code to the physics bodies

```
soldierLegsBody.collisionBitMask = BodyType.none
soldierTorsoBody.collisionBitMask = BodyType.none
```

Or if you need the soldier to bounce off the ground you will need to have to create a new body type for the ground like this:

```
 static let ground: UInt32 = <  A Number >
```

Then you can set teh collisionBitMask to BodyType.ground.

Hope this helps! If you have any questions just leave a comment :)

Comment: What is the difference between a contact bit mask and a collision bit mask? should i just get rid of the contact bit mask? or should i have them both? because without imputing the ground in the collision bit mask the character just falls through the map so why would i have both if i just have to copy all of the info in my contact bit mask and put it in my collision bit mask @Loanb222

Comment: The collision bit mask tells the nodes to collide, so the player would not fall through the ground and the didBeginContact function doesn't run with collision bit mask.

Comment: I didn't mention didBeginContact, I am talking about the contact bit mask thats in my code. when i set the soldierLegsBody.collisionBitMask = BodyType.none the legs start to fall through my other physics boundaries that it didn't before  why is that?

Comment: You would want to create a BodyType for the ground and set the collision bit mask to the ground. The player is falling through the ground because you are saying that you do not want the player to collide with anything. Assuming that you want to make it game over when the player touches the enemy you would want to leave the contact bit mask the same.

Comment: I really want your advice to work lol, but its not, i can't set the dynamic value to false because then the torso wouldn't be affected by gravity. I created the ground in the collision bit mask but that still didn't affect the torso and legs from separating. Any other ideas? lol @loanb222

Comment: Could you put the updated code in your question along with the code you are using to create the ground.

Comment: I just did and i upload a new screenshot as well as some additional code

Comment: Try settings the desertForegrounds body's collision bit mask to the soldiers body and legs.

Comment: why would i touch my desertForeground body's collision bit mask? The hero makes contact with the ground no problem, thats not the issue I'm having its that the torso and legs are still sliding off of each other usually when jumping around @Loanb222 even after i implemented a collision bit mask to the legs and torso

Comment: Try setting the torsos dynamic to true

Comment: the torso's body is already dynamic, when it is not dynamic, it is not affected by gravity so it does not work with jumping because the torso won't go back down

Comment: I ment to set it to fasle and I believe that the dynamic doesn't affect the gravity because you can set affectedByGravity to true.

Comment: yes it does, the dynamic value consists of all PHYSICS impulses applied to it, gravity is a physics impulse, read Xcode definition as well as copy and paste my code to try it @Loanb222

Comment: The best thing that I can think of now is to have a timer run and keep setting the torso's position back to above the legs, I know that it is not the best soloution but it might work.